# Leave out parameters in Scala's function definition

Tags: scala

I can write `???` in the body of a function to leave it unimplemented (where is this feature documented)?

I wonder how can I leave parameters unspecified, i.e. `def f(param1, ???)`.

Comment: what is the point? You can give it a name, type and default value. This way you are not obliged to use it in function

Comment: Such hypothetical `def f(param1, ???)` doesn't seem different from `def f(param1)`. `???` is useful because you can write `???` instead of method body. But if `def f(param1, ???)` were possible why would it be useful? If you don't name a parameter you can't use it further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`???` is a function with return type `Nothing` defined in [`Predef`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#???:Nothing). It throws an `NotImplementedError` when called.

I don't think there is a similar way to leave out a parameter from a function definition. What you can try is to initially give it type [`Any`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html) and then subsequently tighten the type when implementing the function.

Answer (score 2):

> I can write `???` in the body of a function to leave it unimplemented (where is this feature documented)?

This feature is called a [*Function Application*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#function-applications), or colloquially known as a "method call". You are calling [the method named `???`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#???:Nothing), which is [defined like this](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L341-L345):

```scala
def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError
```

> I wonder how can I leave parameters unspecified, i.e. `def f(param1, ???)`.

You can't.